# top command in linux

Tags: linux, top-command

I would like to know meaning of each and every column of top command result.

[image]

If you see the screenshot, It shows lot of Java process under the user 'resoultion'. But here only one Tomcat is running.

%Mem is same for some of the processes, The Consolidation of these numbers are higher than 100.Please explain what does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find everything you need to know about that command and the meaning of the columns, here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

You can also use the following command to access the manuals in the console: man top

Comment: Here, It shows lot of Java process under the user 'resoultion'. But here only one Tomcat is running. 
%Mem is same for some of the processes, The Consolidation of these numbers are higher than 100.Please explain what does this mean?

Comment: Those are multiple processes that run on top of the same JVM. You will therefore get multiple process ids, one id for each process, but the stats will be the same for each one of them as reported by the unique JVM running all the processes.

Comment: Ok Thanks, But %Mem is 20 for all the processes, and when we consolidate it's higher than 100. Could you please clarify on it?

Comment: There are multiple processes, that run on a single JVM which uses 20% of the memory system wide. Each time a process running on that JVM is reporting that 20% of the memory is being used, it refers to the unique JVM instance that holds all the processes.

Answer (score 2):

there is a system wide command available

```
man top
```